# Was fällt Euch ein, wenn Ihr "zersterben" seht?

Tags: meaning

Vor kurzem habe ich über das Wort "zerleben" gestolpert. Die Bedeutung (nach Duden) war nicht was ich erwartet hätte. "Zersterben" gibt es (meines Wissens) nicht aber was würde es für Euch bedeuten?

Comment: Vermutlich so etwas wie "in Stücke sterben".

Comment: Das Stack-Exchange-Format ist für Umfragen wie diese nicht sonderlich gut geeignet. Außerdem ist die Frage ohne jeglichen Kontext nicht wirklich praxisnah. Falls Du zum Beispiel *zersterben* in einem bestimmten Kontext nutzen möchtest und wissen möchtest, ob es von einem muttersprachlichen Leser wie beabsichtigt verstanden würde, dann wäre das vermutlich eine für diese Seite geeignete Frage. Gleiches gilt für das Bedeutungsspektrum der Vorsilbe *zer* (sofern die Frage über das hinausgeht, was ein Wörterbuch beantworten kann).

Comment: _"Vor kurzem habe ich über das Wort "zerleben" gestolpert. Die Bedeutung (nach Duden) war nicht was ich erwartet hätte."_ Was bedeutet es denn und was hattest du vermutet, dass es bedeutet?

Comment: Œlrim hat Recht: Es bedeutet schlicht so etwas wie "in Stücke sterben" oder allgemeiner "kaputt sterben", was natürlich in derRegel nur in extremer, bildlicher Sprache Sinn ergibt. Beispiel: "... brach er dem anderen Gesellen mit Gewalt den Mund von einander und goß ihm den Wein hinunter, worauf dieser ebenfalls des Todes verblich. Da ich dergleichen Ceremonien sah, wollte mir das Herz fast vor Angst zersterben, suchte meine Rettung daher in der Flucht." (1798)

Comment: ... so, wie ja auch *zerleben* "kaputt leben" bedeutet. Wer zerlebt ist, hat sich selber kaputt gelebt. Eine zerlebte Wohnung ist von ihrem Mieter oder Eigentümer kaputt  gelebt worden.

Comment: Interessant, ich habe mir nie Gedanken dazu gemacht, was die Vorsilbe _zer-_ bedeutet: ["unabtrennbare Vorsilbe, die eine Teilung, Trennung, Auflösung oder Zerstörung bezeichnet"](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zer-)